# Create a dynamic stored procedure to archive tables using table specific columns as parameters

Tags: powershell, stored-procedures

Trying to write a generic stored procedure which will archive data from different tables with different column. How do I support multiple number of parameters for a stored procedure?

I'm passing table name, columns' name, columns' type from a powershell to trigger stored procedure. I declared a maximum of 5 parameters for a powershell and gave their values as null. If no value is passed for a parameter it will be taken as null. Now I have to create a temp table using these parameters to proceed further in archiving. I can't pass null values to the create table. How do I proceed from here? Or is there a better way to do this?

Code so far-

Config file:

```
<appsettings>
   <add key = "NumberOfParameters" value = "2"/>
   <add key = "column1" value = "[TradeId] [varchar]"/>
   <add key = "column2" value = "[TransactionNumber] [int]">
</appsettings>
```

Powershell Script:

```
$numberOfParameters = [string]$appsettings["NumberOfParameters"]
$nulberofParametersInt =[int]$numberOfParameters
$Columns =@()
for(@j=0;$j -lt $numberOfParametersInt; $j++)
{
  $k=$j+1
  $stringValue = "Column" +$k
  $Column = [string]$appsettings[$stringValue]
  $Columns += $Column
}

.
.
.
$SqlCmd.COnnection =$SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "EXEC SP_storedProcedure " + $TableName + " " + $Columns
$Returnvalue = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_storedProcedure]
    @tableName as VARCHAR(50),
    @Column1 as varchar(50),
    @COlumn2 as varchar(50) = null,
    @Column3 as varchar(50) = null,
    @Column4 as varchar(50) = null,
    @Column5 as varchar(50) =null
as
begin
begin try
  declare @i     int
  set @i =0
  while(@i<5)
  begin
    set @String = '@Column' + @i
    exec('if (@Column' +@I+' is not null)
             set @String = @String +@Column'+@i)
    set @i = @i+1
  end
EXECUTE('CREATE TABLE #Temp('+@String+)')

INSERT into #Temp () exec('select columns from OriginalTable')
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have thus far?

Comment: Done. Please check.